# malloc'ed 3d array generates Data Access Violation

Tags: c, malloc, multidimensional-array

I have a malloc'ed 3d array of doubles in C that is generating a Data Access Violation error when accessed via indexes.

The allocation function: (Simplified version not checking for nulls or freeing if errors)

```
 #define DIMENSIONA 50
 #define DIMENSIONB 30
 #define DIMENSIONC 2

 double *** Array;

 void InitialiseDataStructure(void)
 {
 int Counter = 0;
 int PointCounter = 0;  

 Array = (double ***)malloc(DIMENSIONA * (sizeof(double**)));   

 for (Counter = 0; Counter < DIMENSIONA; Counter++)
   {               
      Array[Counter] = (double **)malloc(DIMENSIONB * sizeof(double *));                                  

      for (PointCounter = 0; PointCounter < DIMENSIONB; PointCounter++)
      {          
           Array[Counter][PointCounter] = (double *)malloc(DIMENSIONC * sizeof(double));

      }

   }
 }
```

The array is then accessed like this:

```
 Array[x][y][z] = 0;
```

This generates a data access violation error and terminates the program.

I have read and tried and come to the conclusion - I am dumb. 
Please help!!!

Comment: If it's C, why have you tagged it C++?

Comment: Because like I said Cody - I am dumb!

Comment: Is the original a global `double ***` too?  Is it accessed anywhere that might expect `double Array[50][30][2]` instead of `double ***Array`?

Comment: @Dmitri: Yes - the original is a global double ***. I searched the project for double Array[50][30][2] and changed them all to double ***. So double **** is expected everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

What is `POINTS_PER_GEOFENCE` in the following `for` loop?

```
  for (PointCounter = 0; PointCounter < POINTS_PER_GEOFENCE; PointCounter++)
```

Shouldn't that be

```
Array = malloc(DIMENSIONA * (sizeof(double**)));   
for (Counter = 0; Counter < DIMENSIONA; Counter++) {               
      Array[Counter] = malloc(DIMENSIONB * sizeof(double *));                                  
      for (PointCounter = 0; PointCounter < DIMENSIONB; PointCounter++) {     
          Array[Counter][PointCounter] = malloc(DIMENSIONC * sizeof(double));
      }
}
```

Note:

- Read [this](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) for casting `malloc()`'s return value.
- You need to check whether the `malloc()`'s returned success and failure before using that.

Comment: @menzies: I suspect your original code has a similar error - as the code works for me with no invalid accesses. If you check it and it appears correct, can you post the error you're getting please?

Comment: @Timothy: The defines in loops of the original are spot on. Not the issue. From the terminal program connected to the device->MPU fault: data access violation

Comment: @Sangeeth: In the original I do and do not use the array if any of the mallocs returned 0 and also clean up with free().

Comment: In that case, I suspect your error is elsewhere. Possibly a double free somewhere? Try running your code through valgrind.

Comment: @Timothy-Can you use Valgrind with ARM Cortex processors?